# Spartacus storefront is not loading on hybris 1905

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have installed hybris 1905 via VM.

Everything else works (B2C Accel, Hybris, HAC etc) except Spartacus store front.

The store front has a loading screen but doesn’t paint the page.
Is anything need to changed to allow the storefront to finish loading for the SPA accelerator?

Answer (score 3):

Some additional information to @geffchang post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62535976/9290007):

- Take a look on the guide https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries/ to ensure, that your frontend application has correct configuration
- Double check your configuration which `B2cStorefrontModule` is using (here you can find an example project here https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/tree/develop/projects/storefrontapp)
- Take a look on Network and Console browser tabs and try to resolve all errors

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow all the instructions from the Spartacus guide: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud/

This includes:

- Configuring OCC Credentials
- Configuring CORS